# Dynamically adjust the height of the tableview cell based on content - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to set the row height dynamically based on the content set in the detail text label, by using the below code in Part A.

I am inserting few lines of text into a cell's detail text label as shown below in Part B

I've looked at other similar questions but none have helped.

Can some one please advice how I can adjust the row height dynamically based on the content of the detail text label.

Part A

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Also tried

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Part B

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "daysIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = days[indexPath.row]

        cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

        var joinedString            = self.availabilityTimeDict[dayName]?.joined(separator: " \n ")
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text  = joinedString
        return cell
    }
```

[image]

Comment: set label top and bottom constrain proper and also set tableView.estimateRowHeight = 50

Comment: @user44776 Essentially the base class UITableViewCell are not configured to your requirement. They are for basic usages(no other stuff other then the way they could be used). If you want the behavior you wish, you need to provide a custom cell. This is just to stress the fact as the answers don't mention it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use custom cell and labels.
Set up the constrains for the UILabel. (top, left, bottom, right)
Set lines of the UILabel to 0

Add the following code in the viewDidLoad method of the ViewController:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

// Delegate & data source

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension;
}
```

**Swift 4:**

// Delegate & data source

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

**Swift 4.2:**

// Delegate & data source

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 2):

give top,bottom,leading and trailing to your lable inside content of tableview.Use below methods of table view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,heightForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
 return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
 return 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- First setup a custom cell and add a label and set its number of lines to zero and give bottom, top, leading, trailing constraints to cell's content view(dont give the height) also give a custom height to cell in size inspector then in viewDidLoad you just need to do,

`tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0`